# detect slow internet connection in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm able to check When there is no internet in my phonegap app using **navigator.network.connection.type** but when the connection is slow(almost not there) how to check detect such situation using any jquery/javascript code??

Answer (score 2):

You could use `setTimeout()` to set a maximum time for a request:

```
var timeout;
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://myservice.com/jsonp",
    data: data,
    success: function(msg){
       // All went OK
      if(timeout != null) clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
});

timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // Request took >= 10 seconds
    // We could kill it?
    xhr.abort();
    // Or send a message to the user and ask whether they want to continue
    if(!confirm("Network connection is taking longer than usual to complete. Continue waiting?")) {
      xhr.abort();
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: `$.ajax` already has a `timeout` option and additionally this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Good point about the timeout option. It definitely answers the question: *but when the connection is slow(almost not there) how to check detect such situation using any jquery*. If the connection takes longer than 10 seconds, I would define that as slow.

Comment: Think long polling. Also: he (and I) wants to know if the connection is slow before making a requests. And I wouldn't say a connection is slow if an upload takes more than 10 seconds.

Comment: You are absolutely free to leave your own answer. This is mine. I'm sorry it's not the one you wanted, but it's the only one I have :)